# Obx does not update RangeSlider GetX

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

Declared out of `Widget build` scope:

```
Rx<RangeValues> values = RangeValues(MIN_USD_AMOUNT, MAX_USD_AMOUNT).obs;
Rx<RangeLabels> labels = RangeLabels(MIN_USD_AMOUNT.toString(), MAX_USD_AMOUNT.toString()).obs;
```

this is in the Container in Scaffold:

```
Obx(() => RangeSlider(
                divisions: 5,
                activeColor: Colors.red[700],
                inactiveColor: Colors.red[300],
                max: MAX_USD_AMOUNT,
                min: MIN_USD_AMOUNT,
                values: values.value,
                labels: labels.value,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  print("START: ${value.start}, End: ${value.end}");
                  this.values = values;
                  this.labels = RangeLabels(
                          "${value.start.toInt().toString()} USD",
                          "${value.end.toInt().toString()} USD")
                      .obs;
                })),
```

My problem: when I change the value of slider I can see that is work in console but the view does not update. The slider is not updating at all.

Answer (score 0):

Its probably easier just to update a couple RxStrings inside a regular `RangeLabels`.

```
  RxString startLabel = MIN_USD_AMOUNT.toString().obs;
  RxString endLabel = MAX_USD_AMOUNT.toString().obs;
```

In the `onChanged` of the slider just update the strings.

```
  controller.startLabel.value = value.start.toString();
  controller.endLabel.value = value.end.toString();
```

The whole `Obx` would look like this, assuming you've defined a `controller` of your `GetX` class.

```
 Obx(
   () => RangeSlider(
     divisions: 5,
     activeColor: Colors.red[700],
     inactiveColor: Colors.red[300],
     min: MIN_USD_AMOUNT,
     max: MAX_USD_AMOUNT,
     values: controller.values.value,
     labels: RangeLabels(
     controller.startLabel.value, controller.endLabel.value),
     onChanged: (value) {
        controller.startLabel.value = value.start.toString();
        controller.endLabel.value = value.end.toString();
        controller.values.value = value;
                },
              ),
            ),
```

That will update the values in the UI.

Comment: Thank you very much. I forgot to reassign the variable with ```value```.